# Positiveness on Laplace Transform of multiplying by step function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, improper-integrals, laplace-transform

The following is a theorem in Differential Equatios book by Boyce & DiPrima:

If $F(s) = \mathcal L\{ f (t)\}$ exists for $s > a \ge 0$, and if $c$ is a positive constant, then

$\mathcal L\{u_c(t)f(t − c)\} = e^{−cs}\mathcal L\{ f (t)\} = e^{−cs}F(s), s > a$.

Conversely, if $f (t) = \mathcal L^{−1}\{F(s)\}$, then
$u_c(t)=f(t − c) = \mathcal L^{−1}\{e^{−cs}F(s)\}$.

I just didn't understand the condition $s>a \ge 0$. Is positiveness important here?